# Display data from API using react component and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

I have this react component which every time it's rendered show the country information that receives via props (country) and using the weather stack API must show also the capital weather at the current time. The first part (displaying the country data that comes from the props) works fine but I'm struggling to get the data from the weather API. I see on console that I'm getting the current weather but can't assign it to weather variable using setState() therefore my app crashes.

This is the component code I have so far, I've tried using `async/await` and `.then` synataxis in case I was mispelling something but always I get the same result:

```
const CountryDetails = async ({country}) => {
    
    const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

    // const hook = async () => {
    //   const result = await axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${WEATHER_API}&query=${country.capital}`);
    //   console.log(result.data);
    //   setWeather(result.data.current);
    //   console.log(weather);
    // }

    const hook = () => {
      axios.get(`http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${WEATHER_API}&query=${country.capital}`).then((response) => {
        console.log('then');
        setWeather({
          temperature: response.data.current.temperature,
          img: response.data.current.weather_icons,
          wind: response.data.current.wind_speed,
          dir: response.data.current.wind_direction
        });
        console.log(response.data.current);
      });
    }

    useEffect(hook, []);

    console.log(weather);

    return (
      <>
        <h1>{country.name}</h1>
        <p>capital {country.capital}</p>
        <p>population {country.population}</p>
        <h2>languages</h2>
        <ul>
          {country.languages.map((lang) => {
            <li key={lang.name}>{lang.name}</li>;
          })}
        </ul>
        <img src={country.flag}></img>
        <h2>Weather in {country.capital}</h2>
        <p><b>temperature: </b>{weather.current.temperature}</p>
        <img src={weather.current.weather_icons} />
        <p><b>wind: </b>{weather.current.wind_speed} direction {weather.current.wind_direction}</p>
      </>
    );
  };
```

sandbox with the whole code: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ride-h3t1j

Comment: Why do you have `async` in your component's function definition? Would just removing it work?

Comment: firstly I was using async/await syntax now I've removed but still don't work

Comment: you initialize `weather` with an empty object and try to access its properties in your jsx. the line `<p><b>temperature: </b>{weather.current.temperature}</p>` will fail when your component is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a codesandbox I created playing around with your code. Since you stated that you're receiving the data from the API successfully, I'm mocking that with my `getWeather` function. In addition to what @Viet answered, there were other issues in the code you provided. See if this helps or if the error still persists, please provide with a reproduced example of the snippet:

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-dhawan-fds81?file=/src/App.js:52-62

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const getWeather = (country) => {
  return Promise.resolve({
    data: {
      current: {
        temperature: "<temperature>",
        weather_icons: "<weather_icons>",
        wind_speed: "<wind_speed>",
        dir: "<wind_direction>"
      }
    }
  });
};

const CountryDetails = ({ country }) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});

  const hook = () => {
    getWeather(country).then((response) => {
      console.log("then");
      setWeather({
        temperature: response.data.current.temperature,
        img: response.data.current.weather_icons,
        wind: response.data.current.wind_speed,
        dir: response.data.current.dir,
        wind_speed: response.data.current.wind_speed
      });
      console.log(response.data.current);
    });
  };

  useEffect(hook, [country]);

  // You should get {} logged here, not undefined
  console.log(weather);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>{country.name}</h1>
      <p>Capital: {country.capital}</p>
      <p>Population: {country.population}</p>
      <h2>Languages</h2>
      <ul>
        {/* You were not returning anything in the callback of the map function */}
        {country.languages.map((lang, i) => (
          <li key={i}>{lang.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <img src={country.flag}></img>
      <h2>Weather in {country.capital}</h2>
      <p>
        <b>temperature: </b>
        {/* As @Veit mentioned, you were accessing the wrong property */}
        {weather.temperature}
      </p>
      <img src={weather.weather_icons} />
      <p>
        <b>Wind: </b>
        {weather.wind_speed} Direction: {weather.dir}
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default (props) => {
  const country = {
    languages: [{ name: "<name>" }],
    flag: "<flag name>",
    capital: "<capital name>",
    name: "<Coutry Name>",
    population: "<POPULATION>"
  };
  return <CountryDetails country={country} />;
};
```

Comment: I'm getting the same result :(

Comment: this is a sandbox with all my code https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-ride-h3t1j maybe the problem came from other side

Comment: Can you please check. This sandbox is empty, no new code than the codesandbox's boilerplate.

Comment: check now on the index.js file seems like I didn't saved it

Comment: if you type on the search inbox swe and click on the button next to sweden you should see the country'details and curentweather

Comment: You are not passing empty object to `useState()`. It should be `useState({})` instead. Here is the updated sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-glitter-if7kp?file=/src/index.js. It has the `undefined` issue resolved, but I was getting 'Network error' from the weather API itself.

Comment: yes it wworks now god it was driving me crazy thank you!

Comment: NP. Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You are just extracting wrong properties from weather state. This works:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const WEATHER_API = "xxx";

const CountryDetails = ({ country }) => {
  const [weather, setWeather] = useState({});
 
  const hook = () => {
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=${WEATHER_API}&query=${country.capital}`
      )
      .then((response) => {
        console.log("then", response);
        setWeather({
          temperature: response.data.current.temperature,
          img: response.data.current.weather_icons,
          wind: response.data.current.wind_speed,
          dir: response.data.current.wind_dir
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(weather));
      });
  };

  useEffect(hook, []);

  console.log(weather);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>languages</h2>
      <p><b>temperature: </b>{weather.temperature}</p>
      <p>
        <b>wind: </b>
        {weather.wind} direction {weather.dir}
      </p>
    </>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <CountryDetails country={{ capital: "London" }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I just tryed like you did but still gettin the same error and on the line where it says console.log(weather) stills returning undefined it's like the setWeather it's not working

Comment: hm, then you should check the API key and country,capital. What was the response from axios.get()?

Comment: What I used:  <CountryDetails country={{ capital: "London" }} />

Comment: I did and it's working fine, actually on the console.log(reponse) inside the .then I see the result and it's correct

Comment: Yes but if I'm pass a country object should not work equally? also I need the country information nit just the capital

Comment: One thing that you are missing for sure, is keeping your `country` prop in the dependency list/array of `useEffect`.

Comment: Sure, I just used a minimal country object. You can use your own country object with full details

Comment: @Kiran you mean this useEffect(hook(country.capital), [country]); ?

Comment: I've just updated the code (removed async, you don't do that for functional component)

Comment: @Viet same error and keep getting undefined on the line where it says console.log(weather)

Comment: I updated the full code. you only need to replace the API key